# Undefined error while accessing $_FILES['file'] on PHP Page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to upload an image using input type="file" but when I seralize the form using JQuery serialize() method I can't able to get file name or other properties using $_FILES on PHP page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="AddNews.js"></script>

<form id="myForm" method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return false;">
   <div class="innerContainer">
      <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="7" width="92%" align="center">
      <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td class="registerForm">Title:</td>
          <td><input type="text" id="title" name="title" size="35" /></td>
      </tr>    
      <tr>
          <td class="registerForm">Image Path:</td>
          <td><input type="file" id="file" name="file" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td class="registerForm">Content:</td>
          <td><textarea cols="35" rows="7" id="content" name="content"></textarea></td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
      <div id="submitButton">
          <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Add News" />
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Below code is Javascript code for 'AddNews.js' file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name="submit"]').click(function() {
       if ($("#title").val().length == 0) {
           alert('Please Enter News Title ');
           return false;
       } 

       var formData = $("#myForm").serialize();
       $.post('AddFormLogic.php', formData, function(response) {

       }, 'json');
    });
});

/*PHP Code of AddFormLogic.php */
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
} else {
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
  echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
}
```

I am not able to access $_FILES["file"]["error"] on PHP page. Undefined index error.

Can some one help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery/8758614#8758614

Comment: For a cross browser solution use normal html post to your php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery will not send input[type=file] serialising the form data. You can use the html5 class `FormData`. Try:

```
var formData = new FormData($("#myForm").[0]);
```

However, this will only work with browsers supporting html5.